# Can Randomize() function select different random values for 4 different registers having same constraint?

Tags: random, system-verilog

How can I make sure that when `randomize()` is called, different values are selected for all these similar 4 registers. I want that they never get the same random value every time `randomize()` is called.

```
constraint range { 
reg1 inside { [0:31] };
reg2 inside { [0:31] };
reg3 inside { [0:31] };
reg4 inside { [0:31] }; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another constraint:

```
constraint u { unique {reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4}; }
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section "18.5.5 Uniqueness constraints".